# Switching between tabs of content, onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner at js and I've run into a roadblock with my code.

My current progress [on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Kr1ss/pen/qmqZJe)

My code:

```js
 function changeImage (element) {
    var n,
        imageData = [
            [
                {
                    src: "http://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/william-defoe.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 1.1"
                },
                {
                    src: "http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/300x/159304.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 1.2"
                },
                {
                    src: "http://uploads.neatorama.com/images/posts/114/82/82114/1433129672-0.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 1.3"
                },

            ],
            [
                {
                    src: "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Sport/Pix/pictures/2008/10/31/1225454147507/Mike-Tyson-001.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 2.1"
                },
                {
                    src: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/Beyonce_-_Formation.png",
                    caption: "Caption for image 2.2"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    src: "http://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/halo-master-chief-1.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 3.1"
                },
                {
                    src: "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Technology/Pix/pictures/2012/3/5/1330958259135/Halo-4-007.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 3.2"
                }
            ]

        ];
    if (element > -1) {
        document.getElementById('image' + element).src = imageData[element][1].src;
        document.getElementById('caption' + element).innerHTML = imageData[element][1].caption;
    } else {
        for (n = 0; n < imageData.length; n++) {
            document.getElementById('image' + n).src = imageData[n][0].src;
            document.getElementById('caption' + n).innerHTML = imageData[n][0].caption;
        }

    }
    return;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeImage(-1);" >Image set 1</button>
<button onclick="changeImage(0); changeImage(1); changeImage(2);">Image set 2</button>
    <div>
        <h1 id="caption0">Caption for image 1.1</h1>

        <img id="image0" src="http://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/william-defoe.jpg" />
    <div>
        <h1 id="caption1">Caption for image 2.1</h1>
      
        <img id="image1" src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Sport/Pix/pictures/2008/10/31/1225454147507/Mike-Tyson-001.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 id="caption2">Caption for image 3.1</h1>
        
        <img id="image2" src="http://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/halo-master-chief-1.jpg" />
    </div>
```

I'd like to create multiple sets(tabs) of content on the same html page and easily switch between them with js. I got the page to change all of it's (current) images with the "Image Set x" buttons. Found the code snippet here on Stackoverflow and tinkered with it a little.

**I'm having trouble configuring the script to allow myself a 3rd set of images (and 4th etc).**

Is if>else function the correct use in this situation?

Seems to me that the function only allows for 2 different states within the page (I might be wrong)

Now to expand on the problem and the project.

The script switches between src of images just fine, but in the future, if I need to make tabs that switch a bigger part of the webpage, including headers, text, (and maybe even css), is there a more convenient way to approach this idea and solve the problem?

All help is appreciated

Comment: Why not just create multiple divs, and hide/show the div depending on which tab you're on?

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks for the idea, it seemed to me that i was approaching the problem from the wrong perspective

Answer (score 0):

As FrankerZ alluded to, just creating a set of div's you can switch between will be the easiest solution by far. Here is a simple example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#tabs>li').forEach((el, index) =>
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.querySelector('#container>.active').classList.remove('active');
      document.querySelector(`#container>:nth-child(${index + 1})`).classList.add('active');
    })
);
```

```css
#tabs li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ACF;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container>div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: none;
}

#container>div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tabs">
  <li>Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
  <li>Tab 4</li>
  <li>Tab 5</li>
</ul>
<div id="container">
  <div class="active">Content of Tab 1</div>
  <div>Content of Tab 2</div>
  <div>Content of Tab 3</div>
  <div>Content of Tab 4</div>
  <div>Content of Tab 5</div>
</div>
```

With this, you can have any number of tabs, and the contents inside each tab can be anything. You don't have to worry about what the content actually is.

The JavaScript basically just goes through each of the `#tabs>li` elements and when you click them, it'll hide the current tab and make the parallel `#container>div` be the new active (so the first tab shows the first container, second the second, etc.)